# Load extra table/data into user object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In Laravel 5.6 I'm  trying to load data into the user object, so I can view user credentials/settings etc.

Whats annoying is I had it working, but for some reason now It seems to have stopped, and I'm not sure what I've changed to break it.

Anyway I want to load two tables, `access` and `settings`.  Both of them have `user_id` field in there with the corresponding `user_id` in.

In my `User.php` class I have two functions:

```
public function access() {
    return $this->hasMany(Access::class);   
}
public function settings() {
    return $this->hasOne(Settings::class);
}
```

I am **not** `Use`-ing them at the top of the class (i.e. `use \App\Access`) if that makes any difference.

And then the Access class looks like:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Access extends Model
{
    protected $table = "access";
}
```

And the Settings class is very much the same:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Settings extends Model
{
    protected $table = "settings";
}
```

However whenever I try and access `Auth::user()->settings` or `Auth::user()->access` I get `undefined index:` error.  It's frustrating because like I said I had it working the other day and I'm not sure what's changed.

Comment: Can you paste the full error message you get?

Comment: @TheFallen If I run `dd(Auth::user()->settings);` I get the error `Undefined index: settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you could try here. First, [Lazy Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the relationships by `loadMissing`:

```
// settings
Auth::user()->loadMissing('settings');
// access
Auth::user()->loadMissing('access');
```

> To load a relationship only when it has not already been loaded, use the loadMissing method

Second, you can use `with` when querying for a user, although it's not as relevant with using the auth facade:

```
User::with(['settings', 'access'])->where('atribute', $value)->get();
```

Last, if you always want the `settings` and `access` relationships to always be returned with each `user` model, set the `with` attribute on the `user` model:

```
public class User {
    protected $with = ['settings', 'access'];
    ...
}
```

I usually define the inverse relationships on models as well, so `Access` and `Settings` would have a `BelongsTo` relationship defined:

```
class Access extends Model
{
    protected $table = "access";

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class Settings extends Model
{
    protected $table = "settings";

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to use the `loadMissing()` function I get the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::loadMissing()`

Comment: Where are you attempting to call these relationships? `Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser` shows it isn't using your `User` model, so I'm assuming it's early in the authentication process?

Comment: That was from my Controller right before I pass it to the view.

Comment: UGH.  Okay I found the problem.  Thanks to your comments, I stumbled accross this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902280/1445985  I had two users arrays in the auth.php file.  Damnit! Thank you though!

Comment: If you want to update your answer, I'll accept it! You helped me get there after all :) and I'm really grateful for that.